# How to make directory in c drive using python

Tags: python, cmd

Hello I want to create directory in c:\program files using this code

```
import os
os.mkdir('C:\\Program Files\\new_dir')
```

but this problem is shown

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\new_dir'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that the user does not have permission to create a directory in the `C:\Program Files` directory.

To fix this, the user would need to either:

- Run the code as an administrator
- Change the permissions for the `C:\Program Files` directory to allow the user to create directories.

Once the above requirements are okay, you should be able to create the directory with somethink like:

```
import os
os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files")
os.mkdir("new_directory")
```

Comment: Could I make something like  [this](https://static-assets-prod-origin.epicgames.com/help/en-US/epic-games-store-c5719341124379/trending-topics-c5719360434843/attachments/8440853726235/mceclip1.png)

Comment: zeyad, please do not ask new questions in comments to another; submit a new question instead.